# CKeditor its auto replacing div with some tags

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I Got big problem with newest version of CKeditor. When I make template like this

```
<div class="cols-3">
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

when im try to make header h1 , ul or something it is replacing my template like this

```
<div class="cols-3">
    <h1 class="col">lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**but should be:**

```
<div class="cols-3">
    <div class="col"><h1>lorem ipsum</h1></div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

and blockquote is replacing like this:

```
<div class="cols-3">
<blockquote>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
</blockquote>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

please help me,

Comment: you can turn off this in configuration

Comment: but how toturn it off? im trying
`config.templates_replaceContent = false;
 config.autoUpdateElement = false;`

Comment: CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;

CKEDITOR.config.fullPage = false;

Comment: sorry but dosent working still when I select from fromat droplist some header is replacing div like this 
`<div class="cols-3">
    <h1 class="col">lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>   `

Comment: then you may replace using regular expression when saving to database

Comment: sorry but I cant do that